# Modules, Submodules and Vector Spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let R be a principal ideal domain, A a unitary left R-module, and p $\in  R$ a prime
( =irreducible). Let pA = {pa | $a \in A$ } and A[p] = { $a\in A$ | pa = 0 } .
(a) R/(p) is a field.
(b) pA and A[p] are submodules of A.
(c) A/pA is a vector space over R/(p), with (r + (p))(a + pA) = ra + pA.
(d) A[p] is a vector space over R/(p), with (r + (p))a = ra.

I have proved (a). In (b) I am unable to prove that a.pA will also be in pA.

I have done c and d. So, Can you please help?

Comment: what do you mean by a.pA? I would understand that a is in R, but am confused why to denote it by a?

Comment: @Sheve I have to prove that pA is a submodule. So, For any $a\in A$ I have to prove that a pA lies in pA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no multiplication operation on a module, only multiplication by a ring-element.

So you need to prove $a\in pA$ and $r\in R$ implies $ra\in pA$.
But this is easy, as $a=pa'$ for some $a'\in A$ then $ra=rpa'=pra'$ since $R$ is commutative, so $ra\in pA$.

Similarly, if $a\in A[p]$ and $r\in R$ then $pa=0$ so $pra=0$ as well, proving $ra\in A[p]$.